# Magento: How do I separate the display of multiple attributes?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I am using this code to display (on the frontend) all assigned attributes of a product in Magento:

```
<?php if ($_product->getData('metal')): ?>  
    <?php echo nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('metal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product )) ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need to separate each  item with a bullet point `&#149;` and a break `<br/>`. How would I edit this code to reflect those changes?
Thanks in advance.

_Sam

Comment: use jQuery to manipulate client side.

Comment: Could you be more specefic? Where/What code would I insert? Teşekkürler!

Comment: Sam, do you bave live site? Give me the link that I would try to manipulate with jQuery. Also, I will look up where its coming from.

Comment: Oguz, I don't have live site. But here is what it is currently displaying based on that code (for example): "18k Gold, Sterling Silver". If I could determine where it is getting the comma from I feel I could easily switch it for a break and bullet

Comment: I found it but I am not sure the function that you are looking. Go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/Abstract.php` and find `getValue` function. You will see an implode function which is imploding attribute values. Try and let share the result.

Comment: this is the second one, open `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Multiline.php` and find `outputValue` function. This is formatiing the attribute value from entity model.

Comment: Thanks Oguz! I swapped out the comma on line 119 of Abstract.php and success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the above code is "working"... make this change:

```
<?php echo "&#149;".nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('metal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product ))."<br/>" ?>
```

the `.` is a string concatenation operator.

Or are you asking how to do it if the above is the HTML of a listing of products? Then this should work...

```
<?php 
$somehtml=nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('metal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product ));
$somehtml=explode("<br />",$somehtml);  // This ASSumes nl2br inserts <br /> between each line and this 
                                        // would lead to the behaviour you want.
                                        // see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php
$somehtml=implode("<br/>\n&#149;",$somehtml);
$somehtml="&#149;".$somehtml."<br/>\n";
echo $somehtml;
unset($somehtml);
?>
```

`explode` makes an array from a string by chopping up the string via the `"<br />"`. `implode` then rejoins the the string by putting `<br/>\n&#149;` between each element. And finally, I add the bullet point to the front and br at the end. When imploding, you still must consider the "outside" of the string.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The original code I posted displays all the attributes but they are separated by a comma, not a bullet point or a break. I tried both you pieces of code and I get the same result, separated by a comma and on the same line.

Comment: If I could figure out where the heck that comma was coming from; it seems like I could just replace it with the break and bullet.

Comment: Huh, maybe try changing the first explode to `$somehtml=explode(",",$somehtml);` Then it will do its work on that comma??

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the output (maybe you want to style the individual value), use explode();

```
<?php $attr = explode("," ,  $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])); 
echo "<ul>";
?>
<?php foreach ($attr as $attrValue) {
    echo "<li>" . $attrValue . "</li>";
} 
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
It is easy: copy attributes.phtml from base if you do not have one in you default package.

Put in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/ folder

Change line 46 from:

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
```

to show separate product attributes:

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, str_replace(",", "<br />", $_data['value']), $_data['code']) ?></td>
```